# sub multiple patterns in a dataframe

Tags: r

I want to subset a data frame according to different col name patterns. I managed to do it for a single pattern see below:

```
df<-data.frame(
  ID=c("AA","AA","BB","BB","CC","CC", "DD", "DD"),
  var.FA=c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),
  var.SI=c(100, 33, 3000, 22, 12 ,34, 12, 78),
  var2.FA=c(10,15,100,20,10,15,2, 4),
  var2.SE=c(100, 33, 3000, 22, 12 ,34, 12, 78))

df[sub('.*\\.', "", x=colnames(df))=="FA"]
```

I tried two approaches that did not work

`df[sub('.*\\.', "", x=colnames(df))=="FA"|"SE"]`

```
df[sub('.*\\.', "", x=colnames(df))==df[grep(pattern='FA|SE',x=colnames(df))]]
```

Expected out put

```
 var.FA var2.FA var2.SE
1      1      10     100
2      2      15      33
3      1     100    3000
4      2      20      22
5      1      10      12
6      2      15      34
7      1       2      12
8      2       4      78
```

Comment: `df[grep("(FA|SE)$", names(df))]` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple elements, use `%in%`

```
df[sub('.*\\.', "", x=colnames(df)) %in% c('FA', 'SE')]
```